# "Bare Metal" like Virtualization

Tags: virtualization

I know this question might appear very generic, but I imagine that the solution is not that simple and there are many other users intrested in the outcome.

So what I would like to do is not to complicated, I use a server with KVM and run a Windows VM on this. I use my thin client to connect and would like to have the same expireince as on a powerfull (bare metal) workstation. Meaning, I would like to stream Videos, use Software Products with a extensive UIs, etc...

At first glance, I will use some powerfull hardware, a stable GBit Lan and configure GPU passthrought - thath should do the job, right?

But when it comes to connecting everything becomes sliggish. Windows runs like a charm, but streams won't as RDP isn't fast enoght and so the other applications will suffer.

I'm wondering if there is a setup to enable this - Including software (as an RDP replacement) and hardware (some spicific thin client requirements?).

There is "better streaming" support for single applications like Steam for games, but what about a whole OS (Yes, I'd like to achive it with Windows)?

Comment: What's a bare metal virtualization?  That's sort of an oxymoron.

Comment: As I discribed, I want to get a bare metal "feeling" when using a virtual machine over the network instead of the usual sluggish RDP UI.

Comment: You saw the movie "Jaws"?  What you need is a bigger boat.